# Python: Sort a list of list where inner list with different length?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I found the question about how to sort a list of list, but my problem is that my inner lists have different length and I want to sort them based on the last item of my inner list.

For example, I have a list:

```
[ [1, 2, 3],

[2, 4] ]
```

And I want to sort them based on the last item in my inner list, i.e. "3" and "4".

So, is there a good way to do this?

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: `L.sort(key=lambda l: l[-1])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at python built-in [sorted](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) function.

```
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[-1])
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 4]]

>>> sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[-1], reverse=True) # reverse verstin
[[2, 4], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `key` parameter to sort, and then look into either using `len(...)` to calculate the last item, or how negative indexes work.

Good luck!